# How to extract a command from a string - python

Tags: python

I have a command like this:

```
test = ('print( "It works!" )' )
```

and I want to use the command which is inside of that string.
Do you know how can I extract it and use it?

Thank you very much,
Remus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `exec` but make **sure** you trust the code, ie. don't run this on user submitted code for security reasons

```
>>> test = ('print( "It works!" )' )
>>> exec test
It works!
```

Comment: To point out why this can be bad if you can't trust the string, consider `test = "del __builtins__"`.  It's short and sweet, and it cripples python - but not the computer, which is one of the things a real attacker would be trying to do.